# Censoring bad words in a string

Tags: java

I am trying to create a function to replace all the bad words in a string with an asterisk in the middle, and here is what I came up with.

```
public class Censor {
    public static String AsteriskCensor(String text){
        String[] word_list = text.split("\\s+");
        String result = "";
        ArrayList<String> BadWords = new ArrayList<String>();
        BadWords.add("word1");
        BadWords.add("word2");
        BadWords.add("word3");
        BadWords.add("word4");
        BadWords.add("word5");
        BadWords.add("word6");

        ArrayList<String> WordFix = new ArrayList<String>();
        WordFix.add("w*rd1");
        WordFix.add("w*rd2");
        WordFix.add("w*rd3");
        WordFix.add("w*rd4");
        WordFix.add("w*rd5");
        WordFix.add("w*rd6");

        int index = 0;
        for (String i : word_list)
        {
             if (BadWords.contains(i)){
                word_list[index] = WordFix.get(BadWords.indexOf(i));
                index++;
            } 
        }
        for (String i : word_list)
            result += i + ' ';
    
        return result;
    }
```

My idea was to break it down into single words, then replace the word if you encounter a bad word, but so far it is not doing anything. Can someone tell me where did I go wrong? I am quite new to the language

Comment: What do you mean "it's not doing anything"? Where do you use that method? How do you call it?

Comment: Seems like a better job for a `Map` rather than two `List`s.

Comment: Also, while that `if` is syntactically correct, better indentation and use of braces even if not mandatory would make that part more readable.

Comment: At least you have confusing indentation: there is no curly brace immediately following `if (BadWords.contains(i))`, but the next statement is not indented properly. `index++` is always executed, regardless of whether `BadWords.contains(i)` is true.

Comment: @MCEmperor Okay I have fixed that already, and still it is not doing anything.

Comment: Also, you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names and method names are written in camelCase, so they start with lowercase and do not contain underscores.

Comment: @Phong2902 If you have fixed that, you should edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: personally, I would have just a list with "bad words", and create a method that, if recognized, transforms it in a value with asterisks.

Comment: your `index` is not evolving when it should.  It should be incremented on every iteration, since you are looking to the next word in your text.

Comment: @Phong2902 Your `index++` must be moved out of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you move the `index++` to out of the `if` statement, then your code works fine.

[<kbd>Online demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/f5jerO)

However, it won't work properly if there are any punctuation marks immediately following a word to be censored. For example, the sentence *"We have word1 to word6, and they are censored"*, then only *"word1"* will be censored, due to the comma immediately following the word.

I personally would approach this differently. Instead of maintaining two lists, you could also create a `Map` which maps the bad words to their censored counterparts:

```java
static String censor(String text) {
    Map<String, String> filters = Map.of(
        "hello", "h*llo",
        "world", "w*rld",
        "apple", "*****"
    );
    for (var filter : filters.entrySet()) {
        text = text.replace(filter.getKey(), filter.getValue());
    }
    return text;
}
```

Of course, this is code is still a little naive, because it will also filter words like 'applet', because the word 'applet' *contains* 'apple'. That's probably not what you want.

Instead, we need to tweak the code a little, so the found words must be whole words, that is, not part of another word. You can fix this by replacing the body of the `for` loop by this:

```java
String pattern = "\\b" + Pattern.quote(filter.getKey()) + "\\b";
text = text.replaceAll(pattern, filter.getValue());
```

It replaces text using a *regular expression*. The `\b` is a word-boundary character, which makes sure it only matches the start or end of a word. This way, words like 'dapple' and 'applet' are no longer matched.

[<kbd>Online demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/LuAb3J)

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you so much